# Vector-valued function to describe a hyberboloid

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I need to find a vector-valued function to describe the quadric surface $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$. I could use the identity $\cosh^2 u - \sinh^2 u = 1$, but I'm not sure how. The best I could arrive at is $\vec{g}(u,v) = (\sqrt{u^2+1}\cos v, \sqrt{u^2+1} \sin v, u^2+1$), but it only gives the upper potion of the hyperboloid. Or $\vec{g}(u,v)=(\sec u \cos v, \sec u \sin v, \sec u)$, but I don't think this gives the correct surface. Would someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that if you have a curve in the $xz$-plane, $\alpha(u) = (f(u),0,g(u))$, with $f(u) > 0$ and $a < u < b$ (this only means that the curve does not touch the $z$ axis), then the surface generated by the revolution is given by $${\bf x}(u,v) = (f(u)\cos v, f(u) \sin v, g(u)),$$ with $u$ in the same interval and $0 < v < 2\pi$. You already have the identity $$\cosh^2u-\sinh^2u = 1.$$ Then the curve $\alpha(u) = (\cosh u, 0 , \sinh u)$ is the hyperbola in the $xz$-axis. The parametrization you want is: $${\bf x}(u,v) = (\cosh u \cos v, \cosh u \sin v, \sinh u).$$